# Excel VBA: Range.Match keeps returning nothing

Tags: vba, excel

I really tried to solve this error on my own but I just can't seem to get it figured out. I have a range of cells that I am trying to find a particular value in and it keeps returning nothing even though I know the value is there and I know that the search value matches the value in the range.

```
Dim targetDate As Date
Dim rng As Range

targetDate = Sheet1.Cells(3,3).Value 
'the Year(targetDate) evaluates to 2015 and the search range has values 2015 at C1 and value 2016 at O1
'All the other cells are blank, unformatted, and the two values in the range are in general format 
Set rng = Sheet2.Range("A1:Z1").Find(What:=Year(targetDate), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
```

Everything I've tried so far causes rng to be nothing. I know that some of the input values of Find carry over to the next call so I have reset them in this call to ensure I'm getting the right settings. I have tried setting up an if to compare Year(targetDate) and Range("C1").Value and it evaluated to true. The weirdest thing is that this code worked for me for at least a few runs of the macro and now refuses to work. I've exhausted all my ideas for a solution, I know this question is very specific but hopefully someone can help. If you need any more info just ask.

Thanks

Comment: Does this work `LookIn:=xlFormulas`?

Comment: I know this is a dumb question, but I can't think of any other potential issues ... are you sure that the sheet with the code name of `Sheet2` is the sheet where `Range("C1")` is?  E.g. did you say `If Year(targetDate) = Sheet2.Range("C1").Value Then` when you did the test?

Comment: Yeah I did use the right sheet, sorry I didn't clarify

Comment: I will try it tomorrow and let you know Sgdva, thanks

Comment: Just tried it with xlFormulas and that got it working. I honestly don't understand what the difference is but whatever, it's working now. Thanks Sgdva!

Answer (score 0):

This code was adapted from: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win006.htm

```
Sub Test()
    Dim FindString As String
    Dim rng As Range

    FindString = Format(Sheet1.Cells(3, 3).Value, "YYYY")
    With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z1")
        Set rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            Application.Goto rng, True
        Else
            MsgBox "Nothing found"
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```